# How do I call and initialize the Java Access Bridge API?

Tags: java, java-access-bridge

The [Java Access Bridge API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/access/jab/api.html#jab-api-calls) states:

> The Java Access Bridge API calls are contained in `AccessBridgeCalls.h`
>   and to use them, you must also compile the file `AccessBridgeCalls.c`,
>   which acts as the interface between your application and
>   `WindowsAccessBridge.dll`.

But when I tried to create a dll out of `AccessBridgeCalls.h` & `AccessBridgeCalls.c`, it says missing `AccessBridgeDebug.h` file.

How do I call the `initiateAccessBridge()` method? I am looking to perform tasks similar to JavaMonkey.exe, such as identifying components in a Java Swing application.

When I call `isJavaWindow(int)` from the Access Bridge, it always returns false for all handlers.

Comment: maybe you're building with debug, build just the release so AccessBridgeDebug.h won't be needed

Comment: What language are you calling the bridge from? (C, C++, Java). How are you creating your DLL?

Answer (score 0):

JAB relies on the Windows Messaging mechanism to perform inter-process communications. You have to set up a thread to run message pump loop and call `initiateAccessBridge()` in that thread, otherwise some methods like `isJavaWindow()` will always return `false`.

Here is a C# reference:

```cs
            var accessBridge = new AccessBridge();
            // Use WPF UI thread if there is one
            var messageLoopDispatcher = Application.Current?.Dispatcher;
            if (messageLoopDispatcher == null)
            {
                var readyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                var messageLoopThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    messageLoopDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                    readyEvent.Set();
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                });
                messageLoopThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                messageLoopThread.Start();
                readyEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            messageLoopDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                accessBridge.Initialize();
            });
```